# Hey Guys.What to ask how i am going to implement a 50 50 lifeline in my KBC or WHO WANTS TO BE A MILLIONAIRE? in the following code of mine?

Tags: java

```
package kbc;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class qa {


    String question;
    String answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4;
    String correctanswer;
}
class mykbc{
    final static int noques=25;
    public static void main(String []args){
        try{
            Scanner input;
            input=new Scanner(System.in);
            RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile("hello.txt","r");
            ArrayList<Integer>al=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            TreeMap<Integer,qa>tm=new TreeMap<Integer,qa>();
            long filelength= raf.length();
            for(int loop=0;loop<15;++loop){
                int currentques;
                do{
                    currentques=(int)(Math.random()*noques);
                    if(!al.contains(currentques)){
                        al.add(currentques);
                        break;
                    }


                }
                while(true);

                raf.seek(0);
                int track=0;
                qa cqa=new qa();

                while(raf.getFilePointer()< filelength){
                    cqa.question=raf.readLine();
                    cqa.answer1=raf.readLine();
                    if(cqa.answer1.charAt(0)=='$'){


                        cqa.answer1=cqa.answer1.substring(1,cqa.answer1.length());


                        cqa.correctanswer=cqa.answer1;




                                        }
                cqa.answer2=raf.readLine();
                if(cqa.answer2.charAt(0)=='$'){
                    cqa.answer2=cqa.answer2.substring(1,cqa.answer2.length());
                    cqa.correctanswer=cqa.answer2;
                }
                cqa.answer3=raf.readLine();
                if(cqa.answer3.charAt(0)=='$'){
                    cqa.answer3=cqa.answer3.substring(1,cqa.answer3.length());
                    cqa.correctanswer=cqa.answer3;

                }
                cqa.answer4=raf.readLine();
                if(cqa.answer4.charAt(0)=='$'){
                    cqa.answer4=cqa.answer4.substring(1,cqa.answer4.length());
                    cqa.correctanswer=cqa.answer4;
                }
                if(++track==currentques){
                    tm.put(loop+1,cqa);
                    break;
                }

                }           

            }
System.out.println("Welcome to KBC");
Set myset=tm.entrySet();
Iterator itr =myset.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
    Map.Entry me=(Map.Entry)itr.next();
    System.out.println("Question No"+me.getKey());
    qa temp=(qa)me.getValue();
    System.out.println("A:"+temp.answer1);
    System.out.println("B:"+temp.answer2);
    System.out.println("C:"+temp.answer3);
    System.out.println("D:"+temp.answer4);
    System.out.println("Enter the Correct option :");


    System.out.println("Answer is:");
     String opt = input.nextLine();
     if(opt.equals("A"))
     {
        if(temp.answer1.equals(temp.correctanswer))
        {
             temp.correctanswer = temp.answer1;      
             System.out.println ("correct answer");
             System.out.println("You Won 1000rs :)\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("You Lost :(");
            break;
        }
     }
     if(opt.equals("B"))
     {
        if(temp.answer2.equals(temp.correctanswer))
        {
             temp.correctanswer = temp.answer2;      
             System.out.println ("correct answer");
             System.out.println("You Won 20000rs :)\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
            System.out.println("You Lost :(");
            break;
        }
     }
     if(opt.equals("C"))
     {
        if(temp.answer2.equals(temp.correctanswer))
        {
             temp.correctanswer = temp.answer2;      
             System.out.println ("correct answer");
             System.out.println("You Won 30000rs :)\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
            System.out.println("You Lost :(");
            break;
        }
     }   
     if(opt.equals("C"))
     {
        if(temp.answer3.equals(temp.correctanswer))
        {
             temp.correctanswer = temp.answer3;      
             System.out.println ("correct answer");
             System.out.println("You Won 40000rs :)\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
            System.out.println("You Lost :(");
            break;
        }
     }
     if(opt.equals("D"))
     {
        if(temp.answer4.equals(temp.correctanswer))
        {
             temp.correctanswer = temp.answer4;      
             System.out.println ("correct answer");
             System.out.println("You Won 50000rs :)\n");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong Answer");
            System.out.println("You Lost :(");
            break;


        }
     }
  }
   raf.close();
  }
  catch(IOException ex ){
     System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
  }
    }
}
```

Hey Guys.What to ask how i am going to implement a 50 50 lifeline in my KBC or WHO WANTS TO BE A MILLIONAIRE? in the following code of  mine?
Another text file of question with the name of hello containing 50 questions.

Comment: I want to be a millionaire. I want to debug your code so that I can be but what is the error?

Comment: Want to implement a life line 50 50 in my game and i don't know how to do that kindly help me in that,

Comment: The problem is you posted a whole lot of code and there is no clear problem statement. Please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have mention it at the top

Comment: You mention an abstract idea of what you'd like to happen. You need to be much more specific than that: What should the program do in that case? Print something specific, pause, wait for input? Describe the desired behavior, the "algorithm" of what needs to happen. So that people that don't know what this "Who wants to be a millionaire" thing is understand it. Also point out how the code you've written relates to the problem and where you were thinking to add the missing piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, just give the player 2 tries to guess. I know that this is not exactly a 50/50 life line However it should act the same. this is because the probability of choosing the correct answer remains the same. For example, in a proper 50 50 life line, the probability of winning is 1/2. the probability of winning normally is 1/4. So, the probability of winning with 2 guesses is 2*1/4 = 2/4 = 1/2. Therefore the chance of winning is the same.

You can accomplish this by using a simple `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `String opt = input.nextLine();`, you can add:

```
        String opt = input.nextLine();
        if(opt.equals("50-50"))
        {

              Vector v = new Vector(); //java.util.Vector;

              v.addElement(temp.answer1);
              v.addElement(temp.answer2);
              v.addElement(temp.answer3);
              v.addElement(temp.answer4);

              v.removeElement(temp.correctanswer);

              String wa = v.elementAt(new Random().nextInt(3)); // java.util.Random;  1 wrong answer
              String opca="", opwa="";
              switch(temp.correctanswer)
              {

                    case temp.answer1:
                    opca = "A";
                    break;

                    case temp.answer2:
                    opca = "B";
                    break;

                    case temp.answer3:
                    opca = "C";
                    break;

                    case temp.answer4:
                    opca = "D";
                    break;

              }

              switch(wa)
              {

                    case temp.answer1:
                    opwa = "A";
                    break;

                    case temp.answer2:
                    opwa = "B";
                    break;

                    case temp.answer3:
                    opwa = "C";
                    break;

                    case temp.answer4:
                    opwa = "D";
                    break;

              }

              System.out.println("After 50-50 lifeline, Your options are :");
              System.out.println(opca+": "+temp.correctanswer);
              System.out.println(opwa+": "+wa);

        }
```